# get duplicate entries in a column for a specific group sql

Tags: mysql

I have a table with 2 columns:

| # | movie_id | episode |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 | 2 |
| 3 | 1 | 3 |
| 4 | 2 | 1 |
| 5 | 2 | 1 |
| 6 | 2 | 1 |
| 7 | 3 | 23 |
| 8 | 3 | 23 |

As you can see, the `movie_id` = 1 has 3 episodes and the episode numbers are correct, but the `movie_id` = 2 also has 3 episodes, but by mistake, episode numbers are duplicated.

Is there a way to get all the movie_ids that have duplicated episode numbers?

The output in this example should be:

```
2,3
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One simple approach uses aggregation:

```sql
SELECT movie_id
FROM yourTable
GROUP BY movie_id
HAVING COUNT(*) <> COUNT(DISTINCT episode);
```

The criterion in the `HAVING` clause ensures that every `episode` associated with a given `movie_id` is unique.

Comment: Will not work correctly when (1) some episode is skipped (for example, there exists episodes 1,2,4 for some movie) or (2) some episode is NULL. Of course OP must clarify does he needs in such movies to be returned.

Comment: @Akina You're coming up with requirements which aren't even stated in the OP.  Where does it say that validating a counting sequence is required?  My answer detects duplicate episodes; this was the main ask of the question above.

Comment: I agree with you. I only try to predict...